# How could I make a line which is inverted to the original

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics

At the moment this is my code:

```
import scipy

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.collections import EventCollection

import math

from scipy import integrate

from scipy import constants

K_b = 1.380649e-23  # Boltzmanns Constant
a_n = 6.022e23  # Avogrados Number
T = 10  # Kelvin
mass = 28
a = 10e-5
def mantleEvolution(tMax, dt) :
    N = int(tMax/dt) + 1
    timeArray = np.zeros(N)
    numberArray = np.zeros(N)
    t = 0
    n_m = 1 #per cubic centimeter
    n_s = 0
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        m_m = float(mass) / a_n
        V_m = math.sqrt((8.0 * K_b * float(T)) / (math.pi * float(m_m)))
    R = math.pi * pow(float(a), 2) * n_m * V_m
    ρ_d = 3  # g/cm^3
    μ_g = 2 * 1.67e-23
    m_d = (4 / 3) * math.pi * pow(float(a), 3)
    n_g = 10e4
    d_g = 0.01  # 1% mass density of gas
    n_d = (d_g * n_g * μ_g) / (m_d * float(ρ_d))
    n_s = n_s + R * dt
    n_m = n_m - R * n_d * dt
    timeArray[i] = t
    numberArray[i] = n_m
    t = t + dt
    i = i + 1
return [timeArray, numberArray, n_s]

timeArray, numberArray, n_s = mantleEvolution(5.0 * 10**15, 5.0 * 10**9)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4, 6.4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.plot(timeArray, numberArray)
ax1.set_xlabel('time, seconds', fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel('number', fontsize=20)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=16)
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=16)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=.18)
plt.savefig('mantleEvolution.pdf')
```

This is the graph I recieve from graphing my code:
[image]

What I wish to find out is how I could plot a second line which behaves the exact opposite where it grows at the same rate the other declines

So for example, something that ressembles this:
[image]

Comment: But your red line doesn't grow at the same rate the blue one does. It fastest grow is at the end, when the blue line decrease is the slowest. And the otherway round: blue line decreases the fastest when the red line grow quite slowly.

Comment: To draw the red line as you draw it in your example, all you have to do is to add `ax1.plot(timeArray, numberArray[::-1])`. But to draw it as you described it, it should rather be `ax1.plot(timeArray, 1-numberArray)`

Comment: Btw, [don't post image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the graph you'll see that the value on the y axis is for both graphs the same for two opposite x values at the x axis. That means that all you want to do is invert the x axis. That is fairly easy done using the formula:

```
new_x = -1 * (old_x - 2.5) + 2.5
```

By the way, I see some interesting comments in your code. What is it that you are trying to do here if I may ask?

Comment: What I am doing is trying to make a code that shows gas molecules in a molecular cloud before a star is made being turned into solid ice during a set amount of time, I'm not sure if that really makes sense I just needed help because this whole thing is so new to me so thank you very much for your help and time